# PhoneGap submitting JSON form data using Jquery .ajax

Tags: jquery, cordova, form-submit

I'm using PhoneGap to develop an app that has a form to fill out. On Submission, the data is supposed to be sent to our hosted site as a JSON object, but the submission is failing and when I request the XMLHttpRequest.responseText, it's blank.

Here's my code

```
$('#myform').submit( function() {   
    var obj = $('#myform').serializeObject();
        $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'myurl.php', 
              data: obj,
              success: function(){
                  alert( "Thank You For Your Submission" );
              }, //end success
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                  console.log(textStatus);
                  console.log(errorThrown);
                  alert("ERROR");

            } 
          });
}
```

I based my code off of a post from http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/ and I can't figure out what's causing my case to fail. This app is Android and the website I'm using is hosted by Yahoo, but I allowed it in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does it say when you `console.log(obj)` right after getting it? What happens when you `console.log(obj)` in the `success` function? What happens if you allow all domains? (to verify it isn't a whitelist problem.) Can you show us the server and logcat logs?

Comment: console.log(obj) outputs the correct name-value pairs for my form data, I tested that. My success function is never getting called because the submission always fails.

Comment: The logcat just logs that the responseText and errorThrown are null, no errors or error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your ajax call.
The problem will probably be authentication.  Does the hosted site require a login of some sort?  It is known that ajax calls with PhoneGap fail to return a 401 error and give a blank one in return (probably like you received).

The issue with that is in the phonegap JIRA ([Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2962?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13636942#comment-13636942)) and is being worked on.
If there is authentication required, u'll need to add an extra option in ur call: `beforeSend`, where you set a `requestheader` containing the authentication header and the **username + password**.

Comment: The page I'm sending the data to does not require authentication, but other pages do. I tried using the simple username and password fields in the .ajax call with no luck, and I'm getting errors with the beforeSend call.